# Generate a random array ignoring a selected value

Tags: python, arrays, random

In Python we can make a random array from 0 to 10 by doing:

```
randarray = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)
```

My problem is that I want to create an array from 0 to 10, BUT in the first position I want to add a randomly generated number, and then append the rest of the numbers without repetition.

This means I first make:

```
first_value =  random.randint(0,10)
```

and for example, if `first_value` is 4, I want to create a random array from 0 to 10 (without repetition) but ignoring number 4. For example, `[0, 9, 5, 6, 1, 8, 7, 3, 2]` . This is what I dont know how to do, so any help would be much appreciated.

Then I just want to append the `first_value` to `randarray`.

```
randarray.insert(0, first value)
```

So the desired output would be: `[4, 0, 9, 5, 6, 1, 8, 7, 3, 2]`)

Comment: Is it ok with repetition of other numbers than the first one?

Comment: Nope, that also has to be without repetition.

Comment: So, you want a shuffled list of the numbers 1-10?

Comment: @folkol, It seems he also needs the first number to be generated separately and then generate the rest of the list. Is that right?

Comment: That would generate the same result, wouldn't it? (I mean, generating it separately, or letting sample do that for you.) Anyway, we are all good since he found what he was looking for :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps -

```
first_value = random.randint(0, 10)
randarray = [i for i in random.sample(range(0, 10), 10) if i != first_value]
randarray.insert(0, first_value)
```

Answer (score 5):

#### It sounds like you are really looking for a [`shuffled`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) list:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> xs = range(0, 10)
>>> shuffle(xs)
>>> xs
[2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 9, 3, 0, 6, 8]
```

#### For a more general way, use [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> xs = sample(range(0, 10), 10)
```

#### If you actually do want to generate the head separately:

```
>>> from random import randint, sample
>>> x = randint(0, 10)
>>> p = range(0, 10)
>>> p.remove(x)
>>> xs = [x] + sample(p, 9)
```

Comment: As I pointed in the post, It's important to make separately the random number, and then append it to the random created list. Anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: And ok Borja. I am curious of why though, care to explain the difference?

Comment: It's for creating arrays for a GRASP algorithm and compare them with the efficiency with a Multi-Start algorithm. For this, and due to the implementation of the method, I must say which is the first number for both executions.

Answer (score 1):

The way is:

1. you have a list
2. you have first number
3. remove number from list
4. shuffle list